# GroupBy LINQ to SQL not working, perhaps

Tags: linq-to-sql, group-by

I'm struggling to get groupby working in LINQ to SQL, im pretty new to it...I trying to groupby g.id but it just wont work...any help would be greatly appreciated...Cheers

```
            IQueryable<GuestList> query = from t in _ttx.Trips
            join l in _ttx.Legs on t.Id equals l.TripId
            join gl in _ttx.GuestLegs on l.Id equals gl.LegId
            join g in _ttx.Guests on gl.GuestId equals g.Id
            where t.Id == id

            select new GuestList()
            {
                Id = g.Id,
                Name = g.Name,
                NoOfLegs = g.GuestLegs.Count()
            };
```

My result is

```
1 paul 3
2 Jim  1
1 paul 3
1 paul 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try is as below.

```
 var query2 = (from ps in query
               group ps by new { ps.Id } into prod
               select new GuestList
                 {
                   Id = prod.Key.Id,
                   Name = prod.Name,
                   NoOfLegs = prod.Sum(c => c.NoOfLegs),
                  }).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey Sampath, big thanks for the reply. It lead me to the answer:)